# wp_insert_post() not working when in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, embed

I have a script which scrapes articles from the web and saves the url to a .txt file. I've created a custom plugin which on activation, loops through the urls and creates a draft post with the content being an embedded article. I'm using the following code in my plugin

```
<?php
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
function my_plugin_activate(){
    my_plugin_install_site();
}

function my_plugin_install_site(){
    global $user_ID;
    $handle = fopen("listOfURLs.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $count = 0;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
            PostCreator('test', 'post', '<iframe src="' . trim($line) . '" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    // PostCreator( 'test1', 'post', '<iframe src="[link]" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>' );
    // PostCreator( 'test2', 'post', '<iframe src="[link]" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>' );
}

function PostCreator(
    $name      = 'AUTO POST',
    $type      = 'post',
    $content   = 'DUMMY CONTENT',
    $category  = array(1,2),
    $template  = NULL,
    $author_id = '1',
    $status    = 'draft'
) {
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $name ),
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_status'   => $status,
        'post_type'     => $type,
        'post_author'   => $author_id,
        'post_category' => $category,
        'page_template' => $template
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data); 
}
```

The *listOfURLs.txt* file is simply a text file in the same directory with a link to an article on every line. I'm only using 5 links to test at the moment. The problem is currently the script does not create any posts when trying to use the loop. The PostCreator() method did work when I coded the method calls manually(as shown by the comments).

I'm also getting the following error when activating the plugin. Not sure it's related as it was still displayed when hard coding the method calls.

> The plugin generated 205 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Comment: [Enable debug](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and get the error details to see what is the error message.

Comment: I did that but the log file is never created in my wp-content, so there's no errors to see.

Comment: If there is this message "_The plugin generated 205 characters of unexpected output during activation_", there must be error details in log file somewhere. If there is no error log at all, maybe your config is incorrect. I've create test plugin that contain warning on activate using `count(true);` that will raise error at **warning** level in PHP <= 7.4. The error message appears in debug log.

Comment: I tried adding that line as well, but still no debug log. I double checked my config and it is definitely enabled.

Comment: I've tested and your code work without any errors. Change the function call to `PostCreator()` in while loop with `error_log(trim($line));` and it is write the content line into debug log file properly. Try to call `error_log()` in while loop to see that the debug log file is created, if it is not then there must be problems with your config file OR .htaccess, .user.ini files.

Comment: This didn't work either, I found a solution though. I ran the plugin on a localhost and debugging worked fine there. Turns out there was a problem with how I was referencing the text file. I used `dirname(__FILE__)` and everything works fine with no errors.